# I flashed my bios and bricked my laptop please help

Tags: laptop, asus, bios

How do I unbrick my Asus laptop without sending it in to get repaired? I flashed bios and it froze, I then accidently turned it off... Now it turns on cd works but  black screen. It's an Asus gaming laptop.

please help.

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu issue. Also, your laptop needs to be taken to service center. No software can help you now.

Answer (score 2):

While this question is off topic, the only thing I can recommend is to take it to your local Asus Service Center which you can find [here](https://www.asus.com/ca-en/support/service-center/).

As said in one of the comments, if the computer is bricked you can't run Ubuntu which means we can't help!

Good luck!